# Async progress in ASP .NET Core middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a web-api with mvc that's doing a bunch of startup initialization which will take a few minutes. I want the url to respond to a request during this time with a progress-indicator. My thinking was to use a middleware to accomplish this something like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
  await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Loading...");

  await Task.Delay(5000); // the initialization-stuff (which is not started here but just waited on)

  httpContext.Response.Clear();

  await _next(httpContext); // continue to my MVC-page
}
```

However this does not seem to work (`ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`). How do I properly clear/reset the respons so that I can write a new real response once the initialization is done.

---

I resorted to something like this instead (good enough):

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
  if (!task.IsCompleted)
    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Loading...");
  else
    await _next(httpContext); // continue...
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about separating your "tasks" into different actions and use ajax to asynchronously call them? Then you can know on the front end how far along you are.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at SignalR to handle the updates to the subscribers: https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Don't want to complicate this. The page is really simple and I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: But creating hacks to do something things like signalr can do better sounds complicated to me as well. Not saying it isn't, but be aware of trying to keep things simple and thereby making it harder.

Comment: You cannot "clear" a response that was already send. A simple solution would be to deliver a "loading" page first and from there start the hard work using a single request from JS.

Comment: HTTP is request/response. Once you've sent your response, you don't get to spontaneously issue a new one without a new request.

Comment: @AndreasZita you can't not complicate this - that's not how HTTP works. One client request, one response. You *can't* "reset" the response and start a "new" one. Anything that sends messages from the server to the client uses complicated techineques like long polling or web sockets. All those techniques require explicit client coding to work. SignalR makes this *easier*, not harder.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah kind of obvious once I realized it. Thought I did something like this in old ASP but I must have remembered it wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can always complicate things but I try not to. SignalR is cool but way over engineered for this simple thing.

Comment: SignalR is the way to go. You can inject your `Hub` into your controllers or services, and directly send messages to subscribers. Seems pretty simpler than imagining any other way

Comment: You shouldn't try to add things to Web that the web doesn't support natively, its not an desktop application after all. Your best go is to simply accept the request and then notify the user when its completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have sent data to the client you can't take it back. You can't replace an existing page, only append.

You can therefore do two things:

1. You delay the response until initialization is complete (likely not feasible).
2. You send something else and end the request. You could make the page that you are sending poll the server using AJAX to see if initialization has been completed. Then, the page can reload itself.

Create a new API endpoint that replies with the initialization status. Make page page poll that endpoint every few seconds.